# How to process the photo bytes returned by Google Contacts API in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-contacts-api

I am successfully retrieving the bytes of a Profile photos for Google Apps domain users using an Oauth2 authorised `UrlFetch`, but I am unsure of where to go from here - in this case i'm looking to include the images in a `HtmlService` delivered page. The bytes are there and if serves as text as webapp i can see the normal JFIF mumbo jumbo output.

I have tried using:

```
'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + Utilities.base64Encode(Response.getAs('image/jpeg').getBytes()) + '" >
```

but caja seems to strip that out (i suspect as chrome dev tools shows an empty `<img>` in the source.

I have tried various means of saving the bytes to a file using `DocsList.createFile()` as blob, bytes and text and so forth, but none lead to a valid image.

Is the data sanitation always going to cause problems here, there is not `ContentService.MimeType` for image so serving the bytes with the correct header won't work.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known feature request and we will see what we can do.

Comment: In fact all i need for this to work is for HtmlService to not encode `+` as `#43;`.

Comment: That's not the problem... as soon as you'd solve that you'd run into a few more issues. But as I said, we will try to address this use case.

Comment: For now I am writing the base64 encoding of returned images to a css file as background image data uris, and I use HtmlService for the templating but write the result out as string text - creating a matching html file full of container divs. Both these files are then in a public folder in Drive; serving from Google Drive using the `webviewurl`. Tt gets me to the same end, but without caja or the `HtmlService` restrictions.

Comment: [a work in progress](https://googledrive.com/host/0B1ktlYt5-E-DenRXMFFLRE02bG8/pictures.html), but it is an example of Google Apps profile images extracted via GAS. Essentially what we were getting at, but by alternative means.

Comment: In fact, the #43; isn't even a problem - that will work in a data url if it is written into the document as an image src (as opposed to being set via JavaScript). But, yes, a known problem.

Comment: thanks for the note - not to prolong this, but i think i was getting a page templated by HtmlService but it was falling down on the encoding. I think this is after I had resorted to writing to file rather than serving html from GAS. I forget now - it seemed a problem at the time.